# Langford strings

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge description

A **Langford string** of order `N` is defined as follows:

- The length of the string is equal to `2*N`,
- The string contains first `N` letters of the English alphabet, each letter appearing twice,
- For each pair of the same letters, there are `M` letters between them, where `M` is that letter's position in the alphabet (`A = 1`, `B = 2`, `...`, `Z = 26`).

For instance, the only two possible Langford strings of order `3` are `BCABAC` and `CABACB`. As you can see, in both of these strings there is one letter between two `A`'s, two letters between `B`'s and three letters between `C`'s. Given a positive integer `N`, output all Langford strings of order `N` (in any reasonable format: print them one by one separated by a newline, return a list/array...).

## Sample inputs / outputs

```
3: [CABACB, BCABAC]
4: [DACABDCB, BCDBACAD]
5: # no output #
7: [GCFBECBDGFEADA, GBFCBDECGFDAEA, GBDFBCEDGCFAEA, GCAFACDEGBFDBE, GADAFCEDGCBFEB, GACAFDCEGBDFBE, GDAEAFDCGEBCFB, GBDEBFCDGECAFA, EGBFCBEDCGFADA, CGDFCBEDBGFAEA, EGDAFAEDCGBFCB, EGBCFBECDGAFAD, AGABFDBECGDFCE, EGADAFECDGBCFB, AGABEFBCDGECFD, BGDBCEFDCGAEAF, FBGDBCEFDCGAEA, BFGBAEADFCGEDC, CFGACADEFBGDBE, EAGAFBEDBCGFDC, BCGBFCEADAGFED, DAGAFDBECBGFCE, EBGCBFECDAGAFD, CEGDCFBEDBGAFA, CEGBCFBEDAGAFD, BDGBCFDECAGAFE, EFAGACEDFCBGDB, DFAGADEBFCBGEC, AFAGBDEBFCDGEC, DFAGADCEFBCGBE, ECFGBCEBDFAGAD, DEFGADAECFBGCB, CDFGCBDEBFAGAE, EBDGBFEDACAGFC, CDEGCFDAEABGFB, AEAGCDFECBDGBF, FAEAGCDFECBDGB, DFCEGDCBFEBAGA, BFCBGDCEFADAGE, ECFDGCEBDFBAGA, DAFAGDCEBFCBGE, BCFBGCDEAFADGE, AEAFGBDEBCFDGC, ADAFGCDEBCFBGE, AFACEGDCFBEDBG, BFCBEGCDFAEADG, EBFDBGECDFACAG, BEFBCGDECFADAG, EBDFBGEDCAFACG, AEAFCGDECBFDBG, AEADFGCEDBCFBG, ADAEFGDBCEBFCG]
12: # <216288 strings> #
```

## Notes

- Langford strings of order `N` can only be produced when `N ≡ 0 (mod 4)` or `N ≡ 3 (mod 4)`,
- You can use both lower-case and upper-case letters,
- You may use subsequent numbers as well (`012...` or `123...` instead of `ABC...`)
- Order of strings in which they should appear as output is unspecified,
- Output can be quite lengthy (for instance, there are over 5 trillion distinct Langford strings of order `20`), so your program doesn't actually need to output them all, but it has to work in theory (given enough time and memory).
- This challenge has been taken from [/r/dailyprogrammer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3efbfh/20150724_challenge_224_hard_langford_strings/), all credit goes to [/u/XenophonOfAthens](https://www.reddit.com/user/XenophonOfAthens)

Comment: [There's a closely related challenge in the sandbox.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2305/8478) While in no way required it's usually a good idea and probably polite to check there as well for duplicates.

Comment: Can we just output an array of numbers?

Comment: @LeakyNun: Sure, why not. I updated the description.

Comment: I refer to [this](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFmZC4KeWJCOjFqcC4sQjpbLl16OjJhCmhILD86M2YtOkgrXzEKaEgsP3Q6Lm1I&input=Mw&args=Wg) (run the program)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (23 bytes)

```
{,2*e!{__f{\a/1=,(}=},}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=4%0A%0A%7B%2C2*e!%7B__f%7B%5Ca%2F1%3D%2C(%7D%3D%7D%2C%7D%0A%0A~p). This is an anonymous block (function) which takes input on the stack and leaves output on the stack in the form of an array of arrays of 0-based sequential integers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 43 bytes

```
:1fd.
ybB:1jp.,B:[.]z:2a
:3f-+$_~h?
t:.m~h?
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFmZC4KeWJCOjFqcC4sQjpbLl16OjJhCjozZi0rJF9-aD8KdDoubX5oPw&input=Mw&args=Wg)